# Re-generating files causes them to be deleted from TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, t4

In my project, some files are generated by T4.
The strange thing is: sometimes the generated files are marked deleted in my Pending Changes view, while showing the add icon in the Solutions Explorer.
When I try to do an Undo, it is not possible, because the files already exists.
Of cause I can delete them, then do an Undo, regenerate them and do a check in, but how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: This is actually a nature of the generator. The file is deleted, TFS deletes.  The file is then re-added, TFS adds the file.  Have you tried checking the file out before doing the generation?

Comment: TFS only deletes them, while the files are there. If I check in the deletion, the icon still shows they are new files, but will not add them to TFS. If I doesn't check all the files I checking in, the files will be deleted for my colleagues. At my PC it's still building, because the files are there, but at my colleague's PC the project is not building anymore.

Comment: There are like 20 places were almost 250 files are generated (over 60 projects in solution). To check them out before every generation is a hell of a job. The problem also happens every time one out of 50 times in only one of the places. This will create a lot of overhead for the developers.